# Simple question on solving a matrix: book may be wrong

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Not sure if we're allowed to do this here but there's a question on Schaum's Linear Algebra 6th Ed (#4.5) that I think is wrong...the question says express $v=t^2+4t-3$ as a linear combination of
$$
p_1 = t^2-2t+5 \\
p_2 = 2t^2-3t\\
p_3=t+1
$$
and I set up my augmented matrix as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&0&1\\
-2&-3&1&4\\
5&0&1&-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but based on the answer it appears to be set up as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&0&1\\
-2&-3&1&4\\
5&0&\bf{3}&-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
How is that bolded number 3..?

Comment: seems like your matrix is the right one

Comment: I believe that it's just a typo.